# Knowing the distance from origin of two points, can you infer their distance from each other?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

This would be in a singular quadrant, so the coordinates of both points would be positive. I am wondering if, given two points and both of their distances from the origin, could you evaluate their distance from each other?

Say I have Point A, and Point B.

I know Point A has positive coordinates, and is X distance away from the origin.

Point B also has positive coordinates, and is distance Y from the origin.

I don't want to actually calculate the Euclidean distance between the points, but rather infer if Point A and Point B are within some variable Epsilon of each other. Given only this information, is it possible to find a solution?

Comment: You could get a bound using the triangle inequalities (this is essentially the algebraic way to do the "quarter circles" thing in the existing answer), but in general the answer you get will be a rather weak bound... If one of the vectors has length $n$ and the other length $m$ then the best you can determine is they are at most distance $n+m$ apart (pointing in opposite directions)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen you need to make bounds for OPs case - both pts are in 1st quadrant. For you, one needs to be in 1st, another in 3rd, or 2nd/4th

Comment: @gt6989b sure, but that just means you get a tighter bound. The existence of a bound follows without any restrictions, and hence answers the OP's question that such a bound exists. The one you mention in your answer is obviously minimal given the constraints.

Comment: All you can say is that the distance between them is at least $|X-Y|$ and at most $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative perspective:

The [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) is controlling here.

Assume that points A and B are in $\Bbb{R^2}$, let O denote the origin, whose coordinates are $(0,0)$, and consider $\triangle$ ABO.

Let $a,b,c$ denote the lengths of the respective line segments $~\overline{AO}, ~\overline{BO}, ~$ and $~\overline{AB}.$

Let $\theta$ denote $\angle$ AOB.

Then:

- $a,b~$ are **known**.
- $c~$ and $~\theta~$ are **unknown**.
- $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab[\cos(\theta)].$

Therefore, $~c~$ can not be determined unless $~(\theta)~$ is specified.

Comment: +1 True, it also follows the $c$ is maximum when $\cos \theta = 0 \iff \theta = 90^\circ$, justifying my speculation below... so the max distance is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Geometrically, $A$ can be located anywhere in the first quadrant of a circle with center at zero and radius $X$, and $B$ - on a quarter circle centered at the origin with radius $Y$.

You need to find places where these quarter circles are closest and farthest from each other. Does this help?

---

**Speculation**

Didn't prove this conclusively but it seems very geometrically motivated that the max distance is achieved when one lies on the $x$-axis and the other on the $y$-axis, which would cause the max distance to be from $(0,X)$ to $(Y,0)$, a total of $\sqrt{Y^2+X^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for this. It was very helpful in trying to actually understand what the problem looked like.

Comment: @RichardMcCormick yw, this is also an entranceway to doing the problem algebraically, which you could write out if you liked, but the Law of Cosines argument is much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

To picturize, consider the following image:

[image: Pic]

Here, If you are given that point $A$ is at a distance of $2$ units from the origin and point $B$ is at a distance of $4$ units from the origin, then from the figure, the point $A$ may lie anywhere on the arc $BC$, which is a part of a circle with radius $2$ units from the origin while the point $B$ may lie anywhere on the arc $DE$ (part of circle of radius $4$ units).
Assume point $A$ is at $F$ then if point $B$ is at $G$ then distance between $A$ and $B$ is $2$ units. If $B$ were at $H$ or $E$ then the distance would have been $2.32$ units and $2.96$ units respectively.

Thus, as pointed out by user2661923, unless we don't know the angle made by the line segment joining the $2$ points, we can't determine the distance between the $2$ points.

Comment: op's not asking for exact distance, but for a max bound...

Comment: @gt6989b my attempt was to present a pictorial representation for easier understanding of the problem.  Anything further is already included in yours and user2661923's answer.